# Redux Thunk Action Creator Not Getting Called

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I have a function within `actions/index` that calls an action creator that dispatches an action but it never gets called. I think I'm missing something in Redux. The DB is a Firebase instance.

```
export function handleInitialVisit() {
  ...
  DB.child('profiles')
    .child(id)
    .set(data)
    .then(res => handleVisit());
}

function handleVisit() {
  console.log('called') // called
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    console.log('called'); // never called
    ...
    dispatch({type: SET_DB_REF, payload: visitReferencePath});
  }
}
```

My only guess is that because I'm not calling this with connect or the store it doesn't have those properties of dispatch and getState. Problem is, I don't need this to be called from a component. I want this to happen before a component is rendered. It is trying to figure out the user before interactions happen and components are rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `dispatch` function to dispatch actions:

```
export function handleInitialVisit() {
  ...
  DB.child('profiles')
    .child(id)
    .set(data)
    .then(res => dispatch(handleVisit()));
}
```

Comment: Makes sense. However, is it not possible (or bad practice) to call redux action creators outside of components?  I want this to be called before I render anything in my application.

Comment: It depends on situation. You can do this by using `store.dispatch(actionCreator())`.

Comment: Ok great, that makes sense. Thank you. But is it bad practice to export the store?

Comment: No. You should do this. Otherwise you couldn't dispatch any actions, even in components.